Why is the reactive variable in my Vue3 component not updating, while it is updating in the composable?
I'm facing an issue with Vue3 and Nuxt3 where a reactive variable currentMatchday within my component isn't updating as expected, despite using a composable to handle its reactivity. Here's the code for my composable useMatchdaySlider:
export function useMatchdaySlider(maxMatchday: number = 7) {
  const currentMatchday = ref(1);

  const goToPreviousMatchday = () => {
    if (currentMatchday.value > 1) {
      currentMatchday.value -= 1;
    }
  };

  const goToNextMatchday = () => {
    if (currentMatchday.value < maxMatchday) {
      currentMatchday.value += 1;
    }
  };

  return {
    currentMatchday,
    goToPreviousMatchday,
    goToNextMatchday,
  };
}

When I try to use this reactive variable in my component, it will not update when either goToNextMatchday or goToPreviousMatchday is called.
<template>
  <div class="pt-8">
    {{ currentMatchday }}
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
const { currentMatchday } = useMatchdaySlider();
</script>

I have tried to watch the reactive state in both the composable and the component like this:
  watch(currentMatchday, () => {
    console.log(currentMatchday.value);
  });


While that is firing in the composable, it is not in the component.
I am using the functions to update currentMatchday in another component.
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center space-x-2">
    <Button variant="outline" size="icon">
      <ChevronLeft @click="goToPreviousMatchday" class="w-4 h-4" />
    </Button>
    <h3>Matchday {{ currentMatchday }}</h3>
    <Button @click="goToNextMatchday" variant="outline" size="icon">
      <ChevronRight class="w-4 h-4" />
    </Button>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ChevronLeft, ChevronRight } from 'lucide-vue-next';
const { currentMatchday, goToPreviousMatchday, goToNextMatchday } =
  useMatchdaySlider();
</script>

There are no eslint or console errors.

What do you see in your Vue devtools? Any ESlint or console errors? Can you please provide a [repro]? The code as of right now is not enough. I think that showing how you use goToPreviousMatchday might be helpful here.
